# Grails3 spring security core 3 cannot use domain objects

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to create a grails 3.1.2 website with spring security core 3.0.4.

I have used this page: 
[Grails Spring Security Core](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/)

I used the following scripts (replacing "website" for my project name):

```
grails s2-quickstart com.website User Role
grails s2-create-persistent-token com.website.PersistentLogin
grails s2-create-role-hierarchy-entry com.website.RoleHierarchyEntry
```

Then I added the following to my BootStrap.groovy:

```
if(User.count()==0) {
        Date testDate = new Date()

        Role userRole = new Role('ROLE_USER').save()
        Role adminRole = new Role('ROLE_ADMIN').save()

        User user = new User("John","password").save()
        User admin = new User("Richard","password").save()

        UserRole.create(admin, adminRole)
        UserRole.create(user, userRole)

        UserRole.withSession {
            it.flush()
            it.clear()
        }

        assert User.count() == 2
        assert Role.count() == 2
        assert UserRole.count() == 2

    }
```

I received an error about not being able to find authorities of the User bean class, so I replaced the getAuthorities method with this (as adding it to the transient list didn't work):

```
Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    if(this.id){
        return UserRole.findAllBySecUser(this)*.role
    }
    else{
        return [] as Set
    }
}
```

Then I try and build again, and receive an exception about the UserRole class.

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodSelectionException: Could not find which method <init>() to invoke from this list:
  public com.website.UserRole#<init>(org.springsource.loaded.C)
  public com.website.UserRole#<init>(com.website.User, com.website.Role)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethodInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:3197) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:3134) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createConstructorSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3434) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:91) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.website.UserRole.create(UserRole.groovy:55) ~[main/:na]
```

How do I get past his error? I have no idea what this particular error means :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a User had a validation error and didn't save. You're using the 2-arg constructor, but if there are more required properties than just username and password, validation will fail and `save()` will return null.

If you change the code to create a user to

```
User user = new User(..., ...)
user.save()
if (user.hasErrors()) {
    println user.errors
}
```

then you'll see what's wrong. Add missing properties after the constructor call:

```
User user = new User(..., ...)
user.fullName = '...'
```

or switch to the traditional Map constructor to initialize it in one line:

```
User user = new User(username: ..., password: ..., fullName: ...)
```